# Zend Framework: how to use baseUrl as used in Code Igniter

Tags: php, zend-framework

In Zend Framework, `baseUrl` adds path as `'/user/local/path_tyo_file'`. Is there any function which adds path like `'http://mydomain.com/images/show.jpg'` , as `base_url` in code igniter does?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332787/zend-framework-this-baseurl-always-returns-the-current-page-why -- It looks like a configuration issue to me, `baseUrl` can return the full HTTP URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set up the baseUrl in your Bootstrap.php file by using an initView method. This is also a good way of doing any general view work and keeping it out of your controllers.

```
protected function _initView()
{
    $view = new Zend_View();

    $view->getHelper('BaseUrl')->setBaseUrl('http://mydomain.com');

    $viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper(
        'ViewRenderer'
    );

    $viewRenderer->setView($view);

    return $view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a code example for where and how you use baseUrl. Where is that path coming from? Do you use Zend stand-alone or with the MVC framework?

In my MVC frameworks I don't have and see any use for the baseUrl and initially the baseUrl is empty and afaik it is something that needs to be manually configured. I don't know code igniter so I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.