# Get base url in model

Tags: php, zend-framework, base-url

I use zend framework to develop my project. I want to get base url with its protocol in some model. I try following lines to do that. But it return empty.

```
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$baseUrl = $front->getBaseUrl();
echo $baseUrl;
```

Can i get base url from that way. What are the best solution to do that. I can use also following line.

```
$baseUrl  = 'http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
echo $baseUrl;
```

But i want best solution. Please help me.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1332872/1100237

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend Framework $this->baseUrl() always returns the current page :( why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1332787/zend-framework-this-baseurl-always-returns-the-current-page-why)

Answer (score 1):

To get scheme and domain you can use this:

```
$request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();
$url = $request->getScheme() . '://' . $request->getHttpHost();
```

The remaining part of url you can generate like this:

```
$serverUrlHelper = new Zend_View_Helper_ServerUrl();
$yourUrl = $serverUrlHelper->serverUrl(
$this->getHelper('url')->url(
       array(
           'module' => 'yourmodule',
           'controller' => 'yourcontroller',
           'action' => 'youraction',
       ),
       null,   // the route 
       true));
```