# How to get baseUrl in ZF2 model?

Tags: zend-framework2

I run a zf2 application in `localhost/zf2` locally. I want to retrieve the application base URL(for example `http://localhost/`) in my model.

How can I get the `localhost` part of URL in model?

Or, how I recognize the project is online or offline?

Comment: Why would you want to get the base url in your model? it's usually something that you need in your view, or maybe controller.

Comment: Hey mate, you're doing it wrong. Your model must not be aware about the view. What do you mean by "project online/offline" ? You want to recognize you're running your application locally or on the production server?

If so, you can use apache's setenv to create an enviromental variable called for instance "CURRENT_ENV" with value "LOCAL". If getenv is not returning back anything, it means this is the production environment.

Still, your model must not be aware of any environment it works in. Model is all about the business rules of your application.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong with MVC architecture. If u want use baseUrl in model, pass baseUrl to model from controller.

But I also was add question to do that when i use ZF1. Sometime it will useful for you.

[Get base url in model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260190/get-base-url-in-model)