# baseUrl view helper not working on ZendFramework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm testing with the new Zend Framework 2, and I found a problem when trying to use the baseUrl view helper, I'm getting the following error when calling `$this->baseUrl()` inside my phtml view file;

Debug Error:

> C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework2\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php
>   line 424 - Uncaught exception
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException' with message
>   'Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create
>   an instance for baseUrl' in
>   C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework2\library\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager.php:424

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This looks like ZF1 feature, ZF2 has helper Zend\View\Helper\BasePath

in the view $this->basePath();