# Linking a stylesheet inside Zend Framework for both index.php and the .phtml files

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework, stylesheet

I have spent the last two nights trying to figure this out.

I have a problem with applying an external stylesheet to every page in my Zend application. The issue is that my external stylesheet is either applied to the index.php file, located in the public folder, or the .phtml view pages which I have created inside the applications folder.

Here's the code I have put inside the Bootstrap.php:

> $view->headLink()->appendStylesheet('css/bootstrap.min.css');

In the layout.phtml I have simply called the stylesheet like this:

> echo $this->headLink();

I have tried both '$this->baseUrl()' as well as placing a '/' before the 'css' when appending the stylesheet but to no avail.

When I place a '/' before the 'css', my index.php also stops locating the file and instead looks for it in the following location:
`http://localhost/css/bootstrap.min.css`

These methods work fine when I run my application (index.php) in the public folder but all the other .phtml view files and their controllers, which are in the applications folder do not locate the appended stylesheet.

When I view the output, the browser looks for the following path, for the stylesheet when, in this case, I'm loading the 'signup' page:
`http://localhost/php_project/public/signup/css/bootstrap.min.css`

I do not understand why PHP is adding an additional 'signup' folder before the css folder.

Up to now I have been unable to locate an answer anywhere on the net. I don't see it wise to crate multiple files of the same stylesheet across my application.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually add a stylesheet in the layout file (not in the Bootstrap) like so:

```
$this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('css/bootstrap.min.css'));
```

Comment: Hi.Thank you for the response. I found a solution which I haven't found anywhere on the net so I'm worried it may pose a security risk. I saved the above line as follows $this->headLink()->appendStylesheet($this->baseUrl('php-project/public/css/bootstrap.min.css'));

Comment: Hmm, if this works for you then you have a problem with `baseUrl`. `baseUrl` should give you the path `/php-project/public/`. If you hardcode this path you'll get problems if you run this project on another server. One better fix would be to hardcode your baseUrl in the config. In this way you'll only have to change it in one place. See how: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1332872/1948627